# Error using DeviceOrientationCamera in Babylon React Native

Tags: react-native, babylonjs

I'm trying to setup a minor project for Android using Babylon React Native and use the device orientation as the camera input. When I try to use a `DeviceOrientationCamera`, the library throws the below error.

```
[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.screen.orientation')]
```

which seems to be coming from [this line](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/blob/229ab36e8329d74bcad00a9e00ee0a18f24e7832/packages/dev/core/src/Cameras/Inputs/freeCameraDeviceOrientationInput.ts#L164)

When I use an `ArcRotateCamera` or a `FreeCamera` instead, the scene loads fine. The code I am using is reproduced below

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, useWindowDimensions, View} from 'react-native';
import {EngineView, useEngine} from '@babylonjs/react-native';
import {Scene, SceneLoader, DeviceOrientationCamera, Vector3, FreeCamera} from '@babylonjs/core';
import '@babylonjs/loaders/glTF';
 
const EngineScreen = (props) => {
  const engine = useEngine();
  const [camera, setCamera] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (engine) {
      const scene = new Scene(engine)
      const url =
        'https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/master/2.0/Duck/glTF-Binary/Duck.glb?raw=true';
      SceneLoader.Append("", url, scene, (sc => {
       let cam;
       try {
         // When FreeCamera is used, the scene renders fine
         // cam = new FreeCamera('FreeCamera', new Vector3(0, 0, 0), sc);

         // When DeviceOrientationCamera is used, it throws an error
         cam = new DeviceOrientationCamera('DeviceOrientationCamera', new Vector3(0, 0, 0), sc);
       } catch (err) {
         console.log(err);
         throw err;
       }

       const canvas = engine.getRenderingCanvas();
       cam.attachControl(canvas, true);  
       setCamera(sc.activeCamera);
      }));
    }
  }, [engine]);
 
  return (
    <>
      <View style={props.style}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <EngineView camera={camera} displayFrameRate={true} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
 
const App = () => {
  const {width, height} = useWindowDimensions();
  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          height,
          width,
        }}>
        <EngineScreen style={{flex: 1}} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};
 
export default App;
```

How can I fix this issue? On a broader level, I want to allow the user to 'look around'(rotate) and 'walk around'(translate) the scene by moving their mobile. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I think this might help - https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/issues/78

Comment: @Iva, Thanks for the link. The error in my case seems to be occurring because the InputsManager is expecting a window object to be there. But since it is being called in React Native, there is no such object. I'm beginning to suspect that DeviceOrientationInputs are not supported yet in BabylonNative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently only touch input is currently supported in babylon native. More details in the discussion below

https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/error-using-deviceorientationcamera-in-babylon-react-native/31454/2?u=ketan_bhokray